# How do I add a thousand seperator to a number?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, number-formatting

Is it possible to add a thousands separator to a number or a selection of numbers?

**Before**

```
42
4815162342
```

**After**

```
42
4.815.162.342
```

I have to perform this operation quite often, which is why I would like for it to be automated and easy to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

As I am still relatively new to vim, if there is a better alternative or if there are improvements to be made, please do let me know.

## Setup

The solution I ended up with makes use of a regular expression that is saved to a separate `regex.vim` file, which is sourced in `init.vim`. The full explanation can be found here:

- [Save commonly used regex patterns in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201584/1113913)

**init.vim**

```
" Regular expressions
source ~/.config/nvim/regex.vim
```

**regex.vim**

```
" Inserts a thousand separator after \0
let sep = 's/\d\(\%\(\d\{3\}\)\+\(\d\)\@!\)\@=/\0'
```

Source the added `regex.vim` before continuing.

### Usage

1. Upon visually selecting a number or multiple numbers with <kbd>v</kbd>, press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter Command-line mode.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl + r</kbd>, followed by <kbd>=</kbd> to allow for an expression to be entered. Type the name that you gave to the regular expression in `regex.vim`, e.g. `sep` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As displayed below, entering any character after the above operation should add it as the separator.

[image: Animation showing the usage of aforementioned script]

Comment: It could be slightly easier to define a custom command... more details to follow

Comment: Ok, details: to make a custom command, you can do something like `command Thousands s/\d\(\%\(\d\{3\}\)\+\(\d\)\@!\)\@=/\0`—then you could just do `:Thousands` to run your substitute. There are more options (like arguments and `!`s and stuff) in `:help user-commands`